# Safely execute a dynamic sql query

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-injection

Consider the dangerous stored procedure below:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ExecDynamicSQL] 
    @sqlToExec nvarchar(2000)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    exec sp_sqlexec @sqlToExec;
END
```

I understand that this is very dangerous because it is very prone to SQL injection and that people could run malicious commands. However, I need to execute INSERT or UPDATE statements for which I don't have a fixed set of parameters and therefore I cannot pass individual parameters to the procedure.

Is there a way to somehow pass an array of name value pairs as a single parameter and then have the stored procedure safely build the query and execute it?

Is there an alternative and safe way to achieve this? I have considered splitting the query into Tablename, SET clause and WHERE clause sections (for update commands) and pass on 3 parameters accordingly, but I don't know if that would remove the risk of SQL Injection.

Comment: This feels like an XY Problem, if I am honest. If you have an `INSERT` against a table there can only be a fixed number of columns, so why do you need a dynamic solution? The same is true for an `UPDATE`, the table still have a fixed number of columns. If you don't want to change the value of a specific colum pass `NULL`  and use `ISNULL`. What you have is horrendously dangerous; sometime could literally run what ever they want.

Comment: Also, why are using `sp_sqlexec`? That hasn't been supported for decades.

Comment: @Larnu I need to use the same procedure to run updates/inserts on tables that could have fields added in the future. I need one stored procedure that can be used with different tables.

What is the new equivalent of sp_sqlexec?

Comment: Then you update your Procedure when you add new columns, @OsPrey . What you've just said confirms that this is a [XY Problem](http://XYproblem.info).

Comment: @Larnu as explained earlier, I need to use the same procedure with different tables.

Comment: Then you have separate procedures nfor different tables...

Comment: You're going down a rabbit hole here. SQL isn't a programming language, it doesn't work like one and should not be written like one. You're trying to use programming language principles here, to make reusable code; that isn't how you design database objects. If you need a procedure to `INSERT` into a table, you create one. If you then need to `INSERT` into a different one, you create **another** procedure to do that. Then rinse, and repeat, for your other tables. Don't create a "one size fits all" procedure; that's a severe design flaw. It's like using a `varchar` for a date and time value.

Comment: I appreciate your concern, but if I change the list of parameters every time I add fields to a table, I would also have to update the executable application that calls the stored procedure accordingly. I cannot do that. The application decides what fields to update based on what changes it detects in a matching table in a different database.
I am already aware of the dangers of procedure I mentioned and that is why I am asking for a way to do it (without having to make changes to the number of parameters every time).

Comment: If it wasn't for the fact that update queries take too long to execute on a linked server (even for a single row update) I wouldn't even use a stored procedure at all.

Comment: *"I would also have to update the executable application that calls the stored procedure accordingly. "* Correct, because that's what needs to happen. You need to update the application and the database at the same time. If you, personally, can't do that, you need to be speaking to your coworker(s) who are responsible for the application's maintenance.

Comment: This is what JSON is for.  Pass the parameters as a single JSON object and use nvarchar(max)

Comment: But if you do decide to continue down the dynamic SQL route, go read Larnu's [blog](https://larnu.uk) on the subject.

Comment: @Larnu No idea you had a blog, cool stuff there!

Comment: Though you *could* achieve it, you're going ot need some **very** lateral thinking to achieve what the OP wants safely from what I've written there, @DaleK . ;) Not sure I'd ever write something on how you would either, considering how adverse I am to the idea (as it is truly not a good one).

Comment: @Larnu - agreed, but you know some people will just do it anyway despite advice otherwise, and reading your writings is never a bad thing :)

Comment: What is application written in? C#? You could generate and pass parameters on the fly based on the format of the table.

Comment: @Charlieface my application is written in VB.Net. It compares tables with a similar schema that are located in two databases (connected via WAN), checks for changes and updates the table with the oldest data. It does generate parameters on the fly be iterating through the fields in the database. The app runs on one of the servers and uses linked servers to update the other. The problem with linked servers is that although SELECT statements work instantly, UPDATE statements take up to a minute each even when updating a single record. And that is why I am thinking of switching to stored procs.

Comment: Then you should consider generating **the stored procedures** on the fly, based on the table definitions (you can get that with `select top (0) from table`), then call the sproc dynamically **from VB.Net**. But maybe [edit] and add a link to the `UPDATE` query plan via https://pastetheplan.com, maybe there is something we can do?

Comment: Thanks at @Charlieface . Hadn't thought about that. I just discovered that there is such a thing as temporary stored procedures. I could generate one based on the structure of the input table and pass individual values for every field. Already doing that for INSERT and UPDATE statements, the problem being with UPDATE statements since they work very slow on linked servers. Something to do with UPDATE commands requiring all the table to be sent over. SELECT and INSERT work fine.

Comment: @DaleK [Ah hahahahahahahahahaha.... hahahaha.. ha ha...... haaaaaaaaaaaaaa.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66011338/2029983) (Did I mention, never use it in production?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although I have covered much of this in the comments, I felt it worthwhile giving an answer to give more of an explanation.

Firstly, as I have mentioned, this isn't a route you should be going down. Yes, you can have procedures that do use dynamic SQL, but these shouldn't be handling such basic things as inserting data into a table, or updating said data.

When using dynamic SQL, you need to first ensure that you are properly quoting your dynamic objects. For *this* that isn't too hard, you can just have a parameter for the object's schema and name and then when you inject them wrap them in `QUOTENAME`. The real problem comes from the latter, the "dynamic" columns.

Firstly, you seem to want a dynamic number of parameters; this is a major problem. You can't trivially, or even easily, parametrise dynamic parameters. You won't be able to pass these parameters as their correct type either; you wouldn't be able to pass a `date` as a `date` for example. I can *imagine* a solution that uses dynamic dynamic SQL (yes, I said dynamic twice), and the `sql_variant` object type, but should you be doing that? No. If you understood how to maintain such a solution I don't for one second think you would have asked the question you have; you would have something that is on it's way there, but needed some help.

So, what is the solution? Well, again, like I said in the comments, you should have separate procedures for each table. You might also want separate ones for `INSERT` and `UPDATE` operations, but you could also use a single one and implement "UPSERT" logic; there is plenty of *good* articles on how to do this so I won't cover it here.

As I mentioned in the comments as well, that means updating your procedures when you update your objects. That is **normal**. I routinely update procedures when an underlying table is updated to have more columns.

At the same time your application developers will then need to update their application code to ensure that pass the new parameters to your procedure. Good devops and relationships between your DBAs, SQL Developers and Application Developers is key, but that's all. Keep those communication channels open and active. When you or your DBA alters the table, adding the new column(s) and amended the objects indexes (if needed) in your development environment, and has informed you the SQL developer, you can then `ALTER` the needed procedures. You can then inform the Application Developer, and they can update the application code.

After that, complete your internal testing, fixe any bugs/unexpected behaviour/performance issues and then progress to the test environment. Get your users to confirm it works as required, and then off it goes to production. In other words, follow the  basics of a good develop cycle.

---

TL;DR: The route you want is wrong, and is never going to scale. Stick to a normal development cycle, and update your database and application code in sync so that new functionality can be provided.

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate answer and the insight. I will definitely have a look at your blog.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I wanted to do something "dumb" here, and I mean truly dumb. I wanted to show how crazy such an implementation would look to try and achieve what you really want; and this does.

A few notes about this:

- Never use this in production.
- Never use this in any environment other than a Sandbox, to try and understand it, and how stupid it is
- I have only written a version for an `INSERT`. I have no interest in writing an `UPDATE`/Upsert version.
- It only handles inserting 1 row at a time, no more, no less.
- Never use this in production.
- No, I won't be writing a version to support multiple rows.
- This uses `sql_variant` and we all know you should never really use that.
- If you don't understand this don't use it.
- NEVER USE THIS IN PRODUCTION.
- I am not explaining this works apart what the comments state in the answer.
- I had to also create a function to get properly quoted object names

  - As such it *should* support user defined scalar data types
  - I have not tested if it does support user defined scalar data types
- It used `FOR XML PATH` so that users on older versions can "test" it.
- Did I mention, never use this in production?

So, there you have it. I won't be supporting this, I have no interest in supporting it, because you should NOT be using it. This was just something I felt like proving how dumb the idea is. It is.

```sql
CREATE DATABASE Demo;
GO
--Creating a new database for an easy "clean up"
USE Demo;
GO
--Single sample table
CREATE TABLE dbo.YourTable (SomeID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
                            SomeDate date NOT NULL,
                            SomeName nvarchar(30),
                            SomeNumber decimal(12,2),
                            EntryDate datetime2(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT SYSUTCDATETIME());

GO
--Create a type for inserting the data into
CREATE TYPE dbo.DataTable AS table (ColumnName sysname NOT NULL,
                                    ColumnValue sql_variant); --Yeah, you saw that right! sql_variant...
GO

--Create a function to return a delimit identified version of a sql_variant's data type
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.QuoteSqlvariant (@SQLVariant sql_variant) 
RETURNS nvarchar(258)
AS 
BEGIN
    RETURN QUOTENAME(CONVERT(sysname,SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@SQLVariant,'BaseType'))) +
           CASE WHEN CONVERT(sysname,SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@SQLVariant,'BaseType')) IN (N'char',N'varchar') THEN CONCAT(N'(',CONVERT(int,SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@SQLVariant,'MaxLength')),N')')
                WHEN CONVERT(sysname,SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@SQLVariant,'BaseType')) IN (N'nchar',N'nvarchar') THEN CONCAT(N'(',CONVERT(int,SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@SQLVariant,'MaxLength'))/2,N')')
                WHEN CONVERT(sysname,SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@SQLVariant,'BaseType')) IN (N'datetime2',N'datetimeoffset',N'time') THEN CONCAT(N'(',CONVERT(int,SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@SQLVariant,'Scale')),N')')
                WHEN CONVERT(sysname,SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@SQLVariant,'BaseType')) IN (N'decimal',N'numeric',N'time') THEN CONCAT(N'(',CONVERT(int,SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@SQLVariant,'Precision')),N',',CONVERT(int,SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@SQLVariant,'Scale')),N')')
                WHEN CONVERT(sysname,SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@SQLVariant,'BaseType')) IN (N'varbinary') THEN CONCAT(N'(',CONVERT(int,SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@SQLVariant,'TotalBytes'))-4,N')')
                ELSE N''
           END;
END
GO
--Sample outputs of the function for varying data types
SELECT dbo.QuoteSqlvariant(CONVERT(sql_variant,GETDATE())),
       dbo.QuoteSqlvariant(CONVERT(sql_variant,N'Hello')),
       dbo.QuoteSqlvariant(CONVERT(sql_variant,'Goodbye')),
       dbo.QuoteSqlvariant(CONVERT(sql_variant,CONVERT(varbinary(10),N'Hello'))),
       dbo.QuoteSqlvariant(CONVERT(sql_variant,CONVERT(varbinary(7),'Goodbye'))),
       dbo.QuoteSqlvariant(CONVERT(sql_variant,SYSDATETIME())),
       dbo.QuoteSqlvariant(CONVERT(sql_variant,SYSDATETIMEOFFSET())),
       dbo.QuoteSqlvariant(CONVERT(sql_variant,1.23)),
       dbo.QuoteSqlvariant(CONVERT(sql_variant,CONVERT(decimal(3,2),1.23)));
GO
--The "solution"
CREATE PROC dbo.CompletelyDynamicInsert @Schema sysname, @Table sysname, @Data dbo.DataTable READONLY, @EXEC nvarchar(MAX) = NULL OUTPUT, @SQL nvarchar(MAX) = NULL OUTPUT AS
BEGIN

    --Let the madness begin
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    --First we need to create the initial INSERT INTO. This is the "Easy" part...
    DECLARE @CRLF nchar(2) = NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10);
    SET @SQL = N'INSERT INTO ' + QUOTENAME(@Schema) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(@Table) + N' (' +
               STUFF((SELECT N',' + QUOTENAME(ColumnName)
                      FROM @Data
                      ORDER BY ColumnName ASC--Ordering is VERY important
                      FOR XML PATH(N''),TYPE).value('(./text())[1]','nvarchar(MAX)'),1,1,N'') + N')' + @CRLF +
               N'VALUES(';

    --Now for the VALUES clause
    SET @SQL = @SQL +
               STUFF((SELECT CONCAT(N',CONVERT(',dbo.QuoteSqlvariant(ColumnValue), N',@p', ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ColumnName ASC),N')',N' COLLATE ' + CONVERT(sysname,SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(ColumnValue,'Collation')))
                      FROM @Data
                      ORDER BY ColumnName ASC
                      FOR XML PATH(N''),TYPE).value('(./text())[1]','nvarchar(MAX)'),1,1,N'') + N');'
    --But we need to parmetrise this, so we need to generate a parmeters parameter
    DECLARE @Params nvarchar(MAX);
    SET @Params = STUFF((SELECT CONCAT(N',@p', ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ColumnName ASC), ' ', dbo.QuoteSqlvariant(ColumnValue))
                         FROM @Data
                         ORDER BY ColumnName ASC
                         FOR XML PATH(N''),TYPE).value('(./text())[1]','nvarchar(MAX)'),1,1,N'');
    
    --But, we can't just pass the values from @Data, no... Now we need a dynamic dynamic statement. Oh yay..?
    
    SET @EXEC = N'DECLARE ' + STUFF((SELECT CONCAT(N',@p', ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ColumnName ASC), ' ', dbo.QuoteSqlvariant(ColumnValue))
                                    FROM @Data
                                    ORDER BY ColumnName ASC
                                    FOR XML PATH(N''),TYPE).value('(./text())[1]','nvarchar(MAX)'),1,1,N'') + N';';
    SET @EXEC = @EXEC + @CRLF +
                STUFF((SELECT @CRLF + 
                              CONCAT(N'SET ',N'@p', ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ColumnName ASC),N' = (SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN ColumnName = N',QUOTENAME(ColumnName,''''),N' THEN CONVERT(',dbo.QuoteSqlvariant(ColumnValue), N',ColumnValue) END) FROM @Data);')
                       FROM @Data
                       ORDER BY ColumnName ASC
                       FOR XML PATH(N''),TYPE).value('(./text())[1]','nvarchar(MAX)'),1,2,N'');

    SET @EXEC = @EXEC + @CRLF + 
                N'EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL, @Params,' + 
                STUFF((SELECT CONCAT(N', @p', ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ColumnName ASC))
                       FROM @Data
                       ORDER BY ColumnName ASC
                       FOR XML PATH(N''),TYPE).value('(./text())[1]','nvarchar(MAX)'),1,1,N'') + N';';
    
    EXEC sys.sp_executesql @EXEC, N'@SQL nvarchar(MAX), @Params nvarchar(MAX), @Data dbo.DataTable READONLY', @SQL, @Params, @Data;

END;
GO

DECLARE @Data dbo.DataTable;
INSERT INTO @Data (ColumnName,ColumnValue)
VALUES(N'SomeDate',CONVERT(sql_variant,CONVERT(date,'20210101'))), --yes, the insert into this will look dumb like this. YOu need to explicitly convert them all to a sql_variant
      (N'SomeName',CONVERT(sql_variant,N'Larnu')),
      (N'SomeNumber',CONVERT(sql_variant,CONVERT(decimal(12,2),1732.12)));


DECLARE @EXEC nvarchar(MAX),
        @SQL nvarchar(MAX);
EXEC dbo.CompletelyDynamicInsert N'dbo',N'YourTable', @Data, @EXEC OUTPUT, @SQL OUTPUT;

PRINT @EXEC;
PRINT @SQL;
GO

SELECT *
FROM dbo.YourTable;
GO

USE master;
GO

DROP DATABASE Demo;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=8b90e12c1878007c269d3564c73e910f)

Comment: I did away with stored procedures and created an API call (through SSL) to which I send the encrypted parameters and values and it does the updating target server side.

Comment: if it's executing "dynamic" statements, I hope you're properly quoting your objects then, @Osprey  and parametrising everything else.

Comment: Yes, the values are @parameterized